# Not able to insert form data in database on button click using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using ajax for first time,not able to solve this problem here is the code fr.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function register(){

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "submit_data.php",
            data:     "username=" + document.getElementById("username").value + 
                    "&email=" + document.getElementById("email").value,
            success: function(html){
                $("#response").html(html);
            }
        });
        }

    </script>
```

and my problem is its not going inside the function also on button click

Comment: In the php script have you put a var_dump(); to see if data is passed correctly? What is the script`s response?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Aren't you getting the post data?

Comment: Where the `submit_data.php` code? What's the problem - are you getting an error , the database doesn't get updated?

Comment: `print_r` the post data in your php file and report the output

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending data in a correct way.

Below is your modified code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function register(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit_data.php",
        data: { "username": document.getElementById("username").value, "email": document.getElementById("email").value },
        success: function(html){
            $("#response").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are sending data in wrong way. Use this code for sending data correctly

```
data: { "username": document.getElementById("username").value, "email": document.getElementById("username").value },
```

Comment: on button click i have called the function but its not working  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="register()"/>

Comment: @shilpa try alert inside this function and use console also that function is calling or not.

Comment: i have used alert after this line  $.ajax({
 ..but its not working

Comment: can you please elaborate ..how to check it m not getting

Answer (score 0):

agree with Yogesh Suthar
additionally if you are using jQuery your code better look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function register(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit_data.php",
            data: { username: $("#username").val(), email: $("#email").val() },
            success: function(html){
                $("#response").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```